# Jquery AutoComplete Not Working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i m working with jquery autocomplete with ajax which works fine in IE 8 and Chrome . But for the  Firefox (version 21 ) the results are not shown in the autocomplete  . But i could find
the ajax success and result in firebug console .
 I could n't find  any other error or warnings in Firebug.  Below is sample code which i m using  . I have just added few alerts for understanding purpose , all alerts are coming fine Chrome and IE . But I could only  find 'Alert  Postion - 1' working in FireFox. Please Help

```
$ ( "#sample" ).autocomplete ( 
{
    minLength: 1,
 source: function(request, response) 
 {
  var qurl="sample URL";
  alert('Alert  Postion - 1');  
        $.ajax({
            url: qurl,
            data: { },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) 
            {  
                     alert('Alert  Postion - 2');  
                    if(data.status==true)
                    {
                        alert('Alert  Postion - 3');  

                        response($.map(data.result, function(obj) { 
                        alert('Alert  Postion - 4');  
                                   return {      
                                        label: obj.value,
                                        value: obj.key                        
                                    };
                                }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     alert('Alert  Postion - 5');  
                    }
            alert('Alert  Postion - 6');  
            },
           error:function()
           {
                alert(' Error');
           } 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net or jsbin or plunker that replicates problem

Comment: which jquery version ?

Comment: @Arun_SE This question was posted long back around 2yr back . As mentioned in the question it's Firefox  version 21